# I've made a web page using html and sass for the first time. But I'm confused about how to write the nested sass codes in my angular project

Tags: angular, sass

I'm unable to decide how am I going to transfer my sass codes in my angular project, because they are nested.

I've 3 sections in my web page. Header, body and footer. The sass codes are nested and now I'm unable to decide how to shift/use these codes in my angular project.

// FULL PAGE STYLE - Where to write this section?

```
.full-page-container{
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

.sub-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

// MAIN HEADER STYLE - Wrote this in the header component sass file

.header-container{
    // background-color: yellowgreen;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;

    #site-logo{
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-top: 1%; 
    }

    #right-header-buttons{
        margin: auto 15px;
    }

    a{
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: black;
    }
}

// MAIN BODY STYLE - Wrote this in the body component sass file

.body-container{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    width: 40%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;

    form h2{
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    #input-search-bar{
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    #input-search-bar input{
        padding: 5px;
        flex: 1;
        position: relative;
        font-size: 20px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
    }

    i{
        padding: 5px;
    }

    form  p{
        margin-top: 5px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

}

// MAIN FOOTER STYLE - Wrote this in the footer component sass file

.footer-container{
    // background-color: yellowgreen;

    .main-footer-elements {
        padding: 1.5%;

        a{
            margin-left: 15px;
        }

        #copyright-info{
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
        }
    }    
}
```

}

Initially, I thought if I add the top section in the style.scss file it'll work. Later I've realized that I've to connect somehow the remaining styles to actually make this work, but I don't know how?

Comment: paste the whole thing in your style.scss nesting is allowed in sass, if that's what confuses you.

Comment: Check out my example StackBlitz template I made. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-template let me know if I can help more.

Comment: @k0hamed I've tried that too. But it isn't working. I'm sorry that I've forgot to mention that. Moreover, this isn't the best practice, right?

Comment: How didn't it work? and by by the whole thing I meant the whole part under `// FULL PAGE STYLE`, the best practice is to do that and to have the `.header-container` block in you header component styles, `.body-container` in the body component ...etc. which I assumed you did as you're asking about the `// FULL PAGE STYLE`

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your project structure in a stackblitz example?

Comment: @k0hamed here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-template2 . What I want to achieve is the main-body should take the entire space available!